# How to mock test REST client?

Tags: unit-testing, rest, mocking, mockito

I have a Rest Service Client which I am trying to test.
This is the client method I'm trying to test:

```
public RestPriceRow getPriceRow(String customer, String product, String qt)
    throws Exception {
    // Prepare acceptable media type
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    // Prepare header
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    HttpEntity<PriceRowDto> entity = new HttpEntity<PriceRowDto>(headers);

    // Prepare response
    RestPriceRow res = new RestPriceRow();

    // Send the request as GET
    try {
        ResponseEntity<PriceRowDto> result =
          restTemplate.exchange(baseURL + "{customerId}/{productId}/{quantity}",
          HttpMethod.GET, entity, PriceRowDto.class, customer,product,qt);
        PriceRowDto response = result.getBody();
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    RestTemplate r = mock(RestTemplate.class);
    restPriceService = new RestPriceServiceImpl();
    restPriceService.setRestTemplate(r);
    restPriceService.setBaseURL("url");
}

@Test
public void prueba() {
    PriceRowDto r = new PriceRowDto("100","200","9","10","0","19/11/2012");
    try {
        when(restPriceService.getPriceRow("100","200","16")).thenReturn(r);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run this test, it throws me a `NullPointerException` when executing `result.getBody()`. (result is null)

Comment: You don't *test* `getPriceRow`, you *mock* it. What do you test? What is your SUT (System Under Test), what are the mocked collaborators?

Comment: i thought i wasnt mocking the service.. so what do i need to change to test getPriceRow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed up the SUT (System Under Test) with the mocked Collaborators. The SUT is the thing who's method you test. The Collaborators play along and return data as needed for the SUT to work.

1. Call the instance of `RestPriceService` that you want to test `sut`: **TODO**
2. Mock `restTemplate`: **OK**
3. Give this mock a name that makes it stick out like `restTemplateMock`: **TODO**
4. Set it on `sut`: **OK**
5. Use `when(restTemplateMock.exchange(...).thenReturn(r)`: **TODO**
6. Call `sut.getPriceRow`: **TODO**
7. Verify that the `RestPriceRow` returned by this call is correct: **TODO**
8. Verify `restTemplateMock`: **TODO**

**Edit:**

If you want to read a *very* good book about the different forms of unit tests, I can recommend [XUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/).

Comment: nice, first thanks for the quick response.
but i have a question about point 5:
the exchange call is part of the method i am trying to test, i think it wouldnt be good to change the code for testing in the service.
am i missing something here?

Comment: Maybee i didnt explained myself to good. The method getPriceRow its not part of the test class, is a method from the service i am testing

Comment: In your code `getPriceRow` is a method of the REST *client*. If you want to test the behaviour of this client *without* the real REST service, you must mock all methods of collaborators that are called by the code you want to test.

Comment: Sorry to insist but i cant get this to work..
On the setUp im mocking RestTemplate and setting it to the service (RestPriceServiceImpl).
Then im using "when(restPriceService.getPriceRow("100","200","16")).thenReturn(r);". And getPriceRow uses exchange. So i think i cant use when.thenReturn on the exchange

Comment: Don't use `restPriceService` in a Mockito method like `when`. `restPriceService` is what you test, not what is called. I recommend to try with a simple example of Mockito to get a hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues here. If you want to test the REST interface, ie make the calls and see the results and check that, I recommend using Jersey Test framework. It runs on a test server and can save a lot of work. ( Assuming you are using Jersey.)

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

But if you want to just test the service layer, you can write normal junit tests.

Comment: This is a question about unit testing, not about integration testing. In unit tests, no remote calls are made.